# Remove all other list items except the one that is clicked using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of this kind

```
<ul>
<li><div class="pname">Name1</div><div class="pid">ID1</div>...</li>
<li><div class="pname">Name2</div><div class="pid">ID2</div>...</li>
<li><div class="pname">Name3</div><div class="pid">ID3</div>...</li>
...
</ul>
```

If I click on any of the list item, rest all other list items should be removed. Can anyone suggest how I could do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming `this` is the clicked `li` element:

```
$(this).siblings('li').not(this).remove();
```

If the click handler is bound to something inside the list item:

```
$(this).closest('li').siblings('li').not($(this).parents()).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace the `ul` contents with the clicked item:

```
$('ul li').click(function(ev){
    $(this).closest('ul').html($(this));
});​
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PpVjc/)

Comment: Works but I'd say actually removing the other elements is more obvious to someone reading the code.

Comment: Sure, fair enough, and also someone could possibly write semantically bad markup where the `ul` contains other than just sibling `li` elements.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution...

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().remove();
});
```